# How to get User Role by the User Id in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, membership-provider

How to get user role of a user with the user id?

I am not looking for getting the current user's role. I want to pass the user's id and retrieve the user's role.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your RoleProvider is configured properly just call [GetRolesForUser()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.getrolesforuser%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) with the username as parameter:

```
string userName = "Bob";
string[] userRoles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(userName);
```

Comment: I did try this. It says the specified method is not supported. Any idea why?

Comment: Do you have a `RoleProvider` configured?  It would help if edit your question to include the providers section of your Web.config